# Google Map - change marker color every n seconds

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

With the jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/t9mv87fs/35/), wanted to check on the correct way to change the Google Map marker's `icon` `fillColor` every 2s to one of `["#FF0000", "#00FF00", "#0000FF"]` sequentially for first marker and to one of `["#0000FF", "#00FF00", "#FF0000"]` for second marker . Should I be using a `setInterval` ?

Comment: Is this what you are expecting? This is just changing from white to black all I changed was remove markers from the setInterval function http://jsfiddle.net/bangsi/t9mv87fs/36/

Comment: close to that, the marker colors need to change every 2 seconds among the colors mentioned in question

Comment: this was close to what I was asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bangsi/t9mv87fs/38/)

This may be what you are after

```
let x = 1;
setInterval(() => {
    let newShade;
    switch (x) {
        case 1:
            newShade = colors[0];
            x = 2;
            break;
        case 2:
            newShade = colors[1];
            x = 3;
            break;
        case 3:
            newShade = colors[2];
            x = 1;
            break;
    }
    let count = 0;
    console.log(`Running fn inside setInterval`);
    for (let marker of markers) {
        console.log(`trying to get icon for ${count+=1} ${marker}`)
        let icon = marker.getIcon();
        icon.strokeColor = newShade;
        icon.fillColor = newShade;
        marker.setIcon(icon);
    }
}, 5000);
```